# Linq to select parent records without children

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a hierarchy as such:

```
- Order
  - order details
      - work order header
         - work order details
```

I want to select work order headers that have no work order details.

I have this so far, but it returns one level up, the order details...I want the next level down, work order headers.

```
IEnumerable<OrderDetail> odWithoutWoDtls = order.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.WorkOrderHeaders.Any(woh => woh.WorkOrderDetails.Count() == 0));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<WorkOrderHeader> headersWithoutDetails = 
order.OrderDetails
.SelectMany(od => od.WorkOrderHeaders)
.Where(woh => !woh.WorkOrderDetails.Any())
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast @steaks. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help!  SelectMany() is really useful.

Comment: Btw, SelectMany() generates a join.  To make it a right join, add .DefaultIfEmpty() to the first parameter of .SelectMany()